# How to Summarise Positive / Negative Number without Adding New Column in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Raw data is following format:

```
Name        Team    Talent
---------------------------
Quill        Red       500
Drax         Red      -900
Ego         Blue     2,000
Kraglin      Red      -200
Rocket       Red       900
```

How can we make a pivot table like below **without adding new column to original data**:

```
Team     Sum_Pos_Talent   Sum_Neg_Talent
-----------------------------------------
Red               1,400           -1,100
Blue              2,000                0
```

Tried adding calculated fields, but the calculation is on the number on pivot table, not on **each row of data**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIFS.

**Sum_Pos_Talent**

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,E2,$C$2:$C$6,">0")
```

Where `C2:C6` is the Talent column, `B2:B6` is the Team Column, `E2` is the name of the team in the other table.

Similarly **Sum_Neg_Talent**

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,E2,$C$2:$C$6,"<0")
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is part of a larger pivot table. So want to make all calculations within that pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data to separate positives from negatives and insert a new row of headers between the two sets (say rename `Talent` to `Sum_Pos_Talent` and for inserted header switch to `Sum_Neg_Talent`). Then, assuming `Team` is in B1 (and in B5) create the PT from multiple consolidation ranges (B1:C4 and B5:C7) eg as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120).